# How to use Unity with Provider pattern when the Provider implementation has Dependency

Tags: c#, dependencies, unity-container, provider

I'm using the [Provider pattern](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/HowToWriteAProviderModel.aspx) and Unity.

This is the typical provider implementation. I have `SomeProvider` as abstract base provider with the abstract methods as well as the logic to instantiate the `defaultProvider`.

```
public abstract class SomeProvider : ProviderBase
{
    #region provider boilerplate

    private const string PROVIDER_NAME = "someProvider";
    private static volatile SomeProvider defaultProvider = null;
    public static SomeProvider Provider
    {
        get { return defaultProvider; }
    }
    private static object providerLockObject = new object();
    static SomeProvider()
    {
        LoadProvider();
    }
    private static void LoadProvider()
    {
        if (defaultProvider == null)
        {
            lock (providerLockObject)
            {
                if (defaultProvider == null)
                {
                    // exception handling omitted for brevity
                    var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(PROVIDER_NAME)
                        as BaseProviderConfigurationSection;
                    defaultProvider = ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(
                        section.Providers[section.DefaultProvider], typeof(SomeProvider)) as SomeProvider;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected SomeProvider() { }

    #endregion

    #region abstract methods

    public abstract bool DoSomething();

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the `ASomeProvider` that implements `SomeProvider`. Note that `ASomeProvider` has dependancy `ADependency` but `SomeProvider` does not.

```
public class ASomeProvider : SomeProvider
{
    #region provider boilerplate

    private string name;
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        this.name = name;
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }

    #endregion

    // Provider pattern needs parameterless ctor and calls this
    public ASomeProvider() { }
    // constructor injection
    public ASomeProvider(ADependency aDependency)
    {
        this.ADependency = aDependency;
    }

    [Dependency]
    public SomeDependency ADependency { get; set; }

    #region methods

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }

    #endregion
}

class SomeDependency {}
```

I use the `ASomeProvider` in a business layer as follows:

```
public class SomeBusinessLayer
{
    public SomeProvider someProvider;

    public SomeBusinessLayer(SomeProvider someProvider)
    {
        this.someProvider = someProvider;
    }

    #region methods
    public bool DoSomethingWrapper()
    {
        return someProvider.DoSomething();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I have the `BusinessLayerFactory` factory for wiring up objects using Unity and returning objects as follows:

```
public static class BusinessLayerFactory
{
    private static UnityContainer container;

    private static void WireUp()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterInstance(SomeProvider.Provider);
        container.RegisterInstance(new SomeDependency());
        container.RegisterType<SomeBusinessLayer>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
    public static SomeBusinessLayer SomeBusinessLayer_Unity
    {
        get
        {
            return container.Resolve<SomeBusinessLayer>();
        }
    }
    public static SomeBusinessLayer SomeBusinessLayer_Self()
    {
        var asomeProvider = SomeProvider.Provider as ASomeProvider;
        if (asomeProvider != null && asomeProvider.ADependency == null)
            asomeProvider.ADependency = new ADependency();
        return new SomeBusinessLayer(SomeProvider.Provider);
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that when I resolve to get `SomeBusinessLayer`, the `someProvider` has its dependency `ADependency` as null.

```
var someBusinessLayer = BusinessLayerFactory.SomeBusinessLayer_Unity;
```

`((ASomeProvider)someBusinessLayer.someProvider).ADependency` is `null`.

The reason for it is that the Provider pattern uses the helper method `ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type type)` to instantiate the default provider and not through Unity's `Resolve<T>()` method.

I can think of doing this without Unity as shown in `SomeBusinessLayer_Self` where I new  `ADependency` if `null` but just wondering if and how Unity handles this.

Method injection or Ctor injection is fine by me.

How do I fix this and have Unity and Provider pattern work together? My main reason for using Unity is to wire up objects in the factory.

I'm not using MVC.

**UPDATE:**

**To fix this:**. hat-tip to [@seth-flowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444610/seth-flowers)

I could not figure out a way without an explicit cast `container.BuildUp<ASomeProvider>(aSomeProvider)`.

```
container.RegisterInstance(new SomeDependency());

//this does not build up the object with dependency
container.BuildUp(SomeProvider.Provider);
//this works and does build up
var aSomeProvider = SomeProvider.Provider as ASomeProvider;
if(aSomeProvider != null)
    container.BuildUp<ASomeProvider>(aSomeProvider);
//compile error
container.BuildUp<ASomeProvider>(SomeProvider.Provider);

container.RegisterInstance(SomeProvider.Provider);

container.RegisterType<SomeBusinessService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: The linked article does not state you need a public parameterless constructor. Removing that unneeded constructor will save you having to configure Unity to resolve a specific InjectedConstructor.

Comment: @Tejs, `ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(settings, type)` method needs a parameterless ctor else throws an exception. It's not clear what you mean in the 2nd part of comment. Any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use [UnityContainer.BuildUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee651459.aspx) in your `BusinessLayerFactory.WireUp` method, in order to flesh out the dependencies on your `SomeProvider.Provider` instance? Your object would still be constructed through your provider implementation, but would have dependency injection through unity.

For instance:

```
private static void WireUp()
{
    container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterInstance(SomeProvider.Provider);
    container.RegisterInstance(new SomeDependency());
    container.RegisterType<SomeBusinessLayer>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    container.BuildUp<ASomeProvider>(SomeProvider.Provider as ASomeProvider);
}
```

The docs for [BuildUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee651459.aspx) state the following:

> This method is useful when you don't control the construction of an
>   instance (ASP.NET pages or objects created via XAML, for instance) but
>   you still want properties and other injection performed.

Comment: `BuildUp` did help me resolve the issue. I'm updating the question. I don't know if there is a better way though.

Comment: Whoops - I was winging it :). Updated the answer.

Comment: Found a better way. I got rid of the `Provider` pattern and went completely with `Unity`. Since `Unity` manages creation of objects, I do not have to use `BuildUp` method.

Comment: That works too... I just figured you needed the provider pattern for that object for some reason.